# how to pass read .text file and make it object

Tags: java

Cars

A dataset of Cars is provided in a file (cars_input1.txt).

The file has the three fields for each car:

```
 Name, Origin, Horsepower.
```

Given this file and given a number N, and an origin O, print N cars that have horsepower greater than the average horsepower of all the cars from origin O.

Note that the average horsepower should be computed from the cars of the given origin and not the whole dataset.

The path to the dataset and the values of N and O will be passed as arguments to the program on command line.

For example, in the dataset below:

```
Chevrolet Chevelle Malibu,130.0,US
Buick Skylark 320,165.0,US
Plymouth Satellite,150.0,US
Volkswagen 1131 Deluxe Sedan,46.0,Europe
Peugeot 504,87.0,Europe
Audi 100 LS,90.0,Europe
```

Given N=1 and O=US, the output should be:

```
Buick Skylark 320,165.0,US
```

Given N=2 and O=US, the output should be:

```
Buick Skylark 320,165.0,US
Plymouth Satellite,150.0,US
```

Given N=3 and O=US, the output should be:

```
Buick Skylark 320,165.0,US
Plymouth Satellite,150.0,US
```

Similarly,
Given N=1 and O=Europe, the output should be:

```
 Audi 100 LS,90.0,Europe
```

Given N=2 and O=Europe, the output should be:

```
 Peugeot 504,87.0,Europe
Audi 100 LS,90.0,Europe
```

Given N=3 and O=Europe, the output should be:

```
Peugeot 504,87.0,Europe
Audi 100 LS,90.0,Europe
```

i tried something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Car.txt"));
    input.useDelimiter(",|\n");
    Product[] products = new Product[0];
    while(input.hasNext()) {
        String name = input.next();
        String origin = input.next();
        String horsepower = input.next();
        Product newProduct = new Product(name,origin,horsepower);
}
public static class Product {
    protected String name;
    protected String origin;
    protected String horsepower;
    public Product(String n, String p, String d) {
        name = n;
        origin = p;
        horsepower = d;
    }
```

i am not getting the desired output

Comment: How does your *wrong* / *not desired* output look?

Comment: what output do you expect and what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You should never split a comma separated value-file the way you do, unless you can be absolutely sure, that the file is valid. Instead use regular expressions:

```
public static final Pattern LINE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([^\\,]+)\\,([^\\,]+)\\,([^\\,]+)");
...

Matcher lineMatcher = LINE_PATTERN.matcher(line);
if (matcher.matches()) {
  String name = matcher.group(1);
  String origin = matcher.group(2);
  String horsepower = matcher.group(3);
  // do something with the values (for example put them into an array)
} else {
  // print some error
}
```

This will likely be more robust, and offer you the option to filter malformed lines and print errors. (This will not filter leading or trailing whitespaces. If you want that, you can either .trim() the results after you get them, or change the expression accordingly)

```
public static final Pattern LINE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s*([^\\,\\s]+)\\s*\\,\\s*([^\\,\\s]+)\\s*\\,\\s*([^\\,\\s]+)\\s*");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
// Reading data from a file using FileReader 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
public class cars {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // variable declaration 
        int ch,i; 
        int numline=0;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String arr[][] = new String[100][100];
    String path=args[0];
        /*
         * Part-1: Parsing input file content
         */
        String delimiter = ",";
        try {
            //Reading file -- Provide location of the input file
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));             
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();         
            String []tempArray;
            //Reading file line by line and storing it in a 2-D array
            while (line != null) {                                       
                /* given string will be split by the argument delimiter provided. */
                tempArray = line.split(delimiter);
                arr[numline] = tempArray;
                numline++;
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println("Input file content:");
            for(i=0;i<numline;i++){
                int j;
                for(j=0;j<2;j++) {
                    System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
                    System.out.print(",");
                }
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
                System.out.println();
            }            
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                br.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /*
         * Part-2: Implementing requirement logic
         */
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int N;
        String O;
    System.out.println("------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Solution of the Above Problem");
    System.out.println("------------------------------");
        N = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); 
        O = args[2];
        double sumHP=0;
        double avgHP=0;
        double hp;
        int originCount = 0;
        //Find average horsepower for origin O
        for(i=0;i<numline;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i][2].equals(O))
            {
                hp = Double.parseDouble(arr[i][1]);
                sumHP += hp;
                originCount++;
            }
        }
        if(N>originCount)
        {
            System.out.println("Value of N is larger than number of details for the given origin");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        if(originCount>0)        
            avgHP = sumHP/originCount;
        int cnt=0; //counter variable to track how many details have been printed till now
        for(i=0;i<numline;i++)
        {
            hp = Double.parseDouble(arr[i][1]);
            if(hp>avgHP && cnt<N && arr[i][2].equals(O))
            {
                int j;
                for( j=0;j<2;j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(arr[i][j]+",");
                }
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
                System.out.println();
                cnt++;
            }
        }        
    }

}

Blockquote
```